# Resizing SVG images in HTML according to window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a logo for my project that i wish to place at the top of my web page. The logo is in SVG format, default size being 1280x256 px. I wish to have this image be resized when the window size is changed. How can I do this? Will I need jQuery or can this be done with simple JavaScript?

Comment: Depending on your svg code, it can be done with CSS alone.

Comment: JQuery is sort of advanced JS, right? Also, link to relevant tutorial would be appreciated. I'm a n00b when it comes to web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually numerous ways to achieve that. Which one to choose depends on what behavior you want to have. Some examples (assuming your `img` has the ID `image`):

**1. CSS using relative sizes:**

```
#image { width: 10%; }
```

The image has always 10% of the screen width and is adjusted automatically.

**2. CSS using media queries:**

```
#image { width: 100px; }
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #image { width: 300px; }
}
```

The image is 300px wide if the screen is wider than 600px, else it's 100px wide. The width is adjusted automatically, but will "jump" to its new value.

**3. jQuery:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $("#image").width(w * 0.1);
});
```

This is equivalent to example #1. Note that you can do your own calculations in JS however you want, so this solution is more flexible than CSS (but probably makes resizing slower). The same goes for #4.

**4. Plain JavaScript:**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var w = 0;
    if (window.innerWidth != null) {
        w = window.innerWidth;
    }
    else if (document.body != null) {
        w = document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    document.getElementById("image").style.width = (w >= 600) ? 300 : 100;
};
```

This is equivalent to example #2.

Besides, jQuery **IS** JavaScript, but many people think it's something like an alternative... jQuery is just a way to make JavaScript development a lot more comfortable in many situations (as you may have noticed in the examples above). ;)